# Bind controls with elements of sibling component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an array called images and I map them to show the images. i put a button for changing them but I don't know how can separate them to change the correct image.it works like change just the last index of every gallery array. for example if gallery has got 4 element it only change the forth element!
I guess maybe it's because of the reference are same...
I'm using redux
thanks.

```
class ImagesInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      val: "",
      currentImgPrev: []
    };

    this.inputFileChanged = this.inputFileChanged.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    let input = this.refs.input_reader;
    input.click();
  }

  inputFileChanged(e, index) {
      let file = e.target.files[0],
        reader = new FileReader(),
        self = this;
      reader.onload = function(r) {
        let img = self.state.currentImgPrev;
        const w = r.target.result;
        img[index] = w
        self.setState({
          currentImgPrev: img
        });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      self.setState({ val: reader });
      console.log(self.state.val);
  }

  render() {
    return (
            {this.props.gallery.map((g, index) => (
              <Col xs={4} className="text-center" key={index}>
                <img src={g} alt="landpic" />
                <Button
                  htmlFor={g}
                  onClick={this.handleClick}
                >
                  Change
                </Button>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  id={g}
                  style={{ display: "none" }}
                  ref="input_reader"
                  onChange={e => {
                    this.inputFileChanged(e, index);
                    this.props.handleSubmit(
                      this.state.currentImgPrev[index],
                      index,
                      this.props.name,
                    );
                  }}
                />
              </Col>
            ))}
    );
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    handleSubmit: (currentImgPrev, i, frameName) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "ADD_IMAGE",
        addedImg: currentImgPrev,
        indexEl: i,
        frameElName: frameName,
      });
    }
  };
};
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ImagesInput);
```

Comment: please provide sample sandbox.

Comment: Would you accept [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59699468/11299053) (push the checkmark underneath voting score) as it seems to solve your problem thoroughly?

Answer (score 1):

While it may be tempting to use Refs whenever no other solution crosses your mind, your particular scenario [doesn't seem](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to be the proper use case for Refs.

As long as your image and controls (triggering certain actions) locked within same parent component (to manipulate images within that component's local state only) you may not even need to involve your global state in order to bind the two.

**Simply pass some image anchor (its `id` or `name` for instance) as a property to corresponding control (button, checkbox, whatever), so that you may trigger actions on desired image upon necessary event**.

See the following live-snippet as a proof of a concept:

```js
//prerequisites
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      { useState } = React,
      { createStore } = Redux,
      { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux
      
//mocking image src data stored within global state,
//setting up dummy reducer and store
const initialState = {imgData:[{name:'Lion',imgSrc:'https://images.theconversation.com/files/243439/original/file-20181101-83635-1xcrr39.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=926&fit=clip'},{name:'Zebra',imgSrc:'https://img3.akspic.ru/fit/95583-ekosistema-griva-zebra-pastbishhe-zoopark-x750.jpg'},{name:'Monkey',imgSrc:'https://img.jakpost.net/c/2017/09/12/2017_09_12_32421_1505189647._large.jpg'}]},
      appReducer = (state=initialState,action) => state,
      store = createStore(appReducer)

//image ui component
const Image = ({imageSource, status}) => (
  <div class="image"><img src={imageSource} style={{visibility: status}}/></div>
)

//parent component
const ImgGallery = ({images}) => {
  const [imagesStatus, setImagesStatus] = useState(images.reduce((res,{name}) => (res[name] = 'visible', res),{})),
        onToggleStatus = animalName => setImagesStatus({...imagesStatus, [animalName]: imagesStatus[animalName] == 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible'})
  return (
    <div>
      {images.map(({imgSrc, name},key) => <Image imageSource={imgSrc} status={imagesStatus[name]} {...{key}} />)}
      <br />
      {images.map(({name},key) => <label {...{key}}>Hide the {name}<input type="checkbox" value={name} onChange={e => onToggleStatus(e.target.value)} /></label>)}
    </div>
  )
}

//use connect to attach global state imgData to images prop
const mapStateToProps = ({imgData}) => ({images:imgData}),
      ImgGalleryContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(ImgGallery)
      
//render parent component inside Provider
render (
  <Provider {...{store}}>
    <ImgGalleryContainer />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```css
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  height:70px;
  border: 2px solid darkblue;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.image img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.1.3/react-redux.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```